# Cast as int or leave as string?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm wondering if there is any reason to cast my variable, which is returned from MySQL as a string, as an int. I'm updating some code and netbeans wants me to use === instead of ==. The problem is that === cares as much about the content as it does the type.

I had: `if($user['user_state']==1){...}`

So I change it to this: `if($user['user_state']==="1"){...}`

or I can do this: `if((int)$user['user_state']===1){...}`

It doesn't make a difference to me if I've got an int or str. I certainly won't be doing any math with this particular variable. And since I'll have to rewrite my conditionals in any case, I'd rather do it the right way.

So, I think my question is what is best practice? Or is this one of those wonderful questions whose answers will end happy marriages like single vs double quotes?

Comment: Loose comparison (`==`) is fine in most cases unless you strictly need a certain variable type, in which case you'll use the strict comparison (`===`).

Comment: Not knowing where your sql string is from, may it ever be possible for the value to be anything other than just e.g. "1", could it have spaces like: "1 " or " 1"?  If user_state is supposed to be an int, I reckon you should treat it as an int - so that excludes your middle option. If you have to be strict, go for option 3

Comment: @TonyWilk Thanks! user_state is stored as an int in MySQL. PHP thinks string is more fun than int, so it gives me the value as a string instead. Makes sense to force correct types. I guess I'll cast it as an int.

Comment: FYI, === will be true if the condition and the type is equal.

Comment: @scrowler I'm self-taught, so I could be way off here, but isn't === usually best practice? === ensures the exact condition I'm looking for (ex `"10000 killer bees"==10000` returns true). From what I've read it is also (ever so slightly) better in terms of performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying reason for Netbeans to suggest such a thing is likely this:

```
"1abc" == 1 // true
```

Strengthening the comparison by applying an `(int)` cast and using `===` will satisfy the editor and purists, but since you would typically trust your database schema, the above cast won't be necessary and you can use a loose comparison instead.

To sum it up, although strict comparisons are a good practice in general it's often considered overzealous when working with external data such as databases and (to a lesser extent) posted data.

That said, it still leaves the matter of making Netbeans ignore these "issues" in a sensible way; having special instructions littered in your code is not a great situation either.